# Python: How can i send multiple HTTP requests and receive the response?

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests, grequests

How can I send like 1000 requests the fastest way?
I know that you can send multiple request with `grequests`:

```
urls = [
    'sample.url/1',
    'sample.url/2',
    ...
]
request = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
print grequests.map(request)
```

But the return is not the content.
What I need is to get the json data, so for example something like this:

```
request = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
content = grequests.json(request)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The items returned are not the content, but they do include the content. You can fetch all of the content like  so:

```
result = grequests.map(request)
content = '\n'.join(r.content for r in result) # raw content
text = '\n'.join(r.text for r in result)       # decoded content
```

You can parse the json like this:

```
result = grequests.map(request)
json = [r.json() for r in result]
```

Sample program:

```
import grequests
import pprint

urls = [
    'http://httpbin.org/user-agent',
    'http://httpbin.org/headers',
    'http://httpbin.org/ip',
]

requests = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
responses = grequests.map(requests)

json = [response.json() for response in responses]
pprint.pprint(json)

text = '\n'.join(response.text for response in responses)
print(text)
```