# How to do parallel requests using python for 1000 requests?

Tags: python, loops, request, python-requests

How to do parallel requests using python?

My code so far:

```py
x = ("address")
x.signin(signin.request())
# this code signs in the user and generate the response how to do a parallel response.
```

Looked into those but couldn't figure out where to use that

```
import asyncio
import requests

 async def main():
     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     futures = [
        loop.run_in_executor(
            None, 
            requests.get, 
            'http://example.org/'
        )
        for i in range(20)
    ]
    for response in await asyncio.gather(*futures):
        pass

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

looked into this thread also:
[What is the fastest way to send 100,000 HTTP requests in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632520/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-100-000-http-requests-in-python)

Comment: is it on linux or windows?

Comment: windows, but its same in both

Comment: i have been successfuling using the `grequests` module in windows. Just `map` the request into a list.

Comment: can you post some link of ex of it

Comment: here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829798/python-how-can-i-send-multiple-http-requests-and-receive-the-response. Let me know if it works.